# Google Places returning different values

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places-api

When I use this:

```
 url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(region.center.latitude),\(region.center.longitude)&radius=15000&type=restaurant&key=\(GOOGLE_KEY)")!
```

I receive the correct output, the city and country name (see image below)

[image]

However, when I use this:

```
 var urlc = URLComponents(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json")!
        urlc.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "location", value: "\(region.center.latitude),\(region.center.longitude)"),
                            URLQueryItem(name: "radius", value: "150000"),
                            URLQueryItem(name: "type", value: "restaurant"),
                           URLQueryItem(name: "keyword", value: "\(searchTxt)"),
                           URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: "\(GOOGLE_KEY)"),
                           ]
        url = URL(string: urlc.string!)!
```

I only receive this output: just city, no country (see below)

[image]

Does anyone know why I might be receiving different compound codes? And what I can do to fix it.
Thanks :)

Comment: There is no `keyword` query item in first call, and radius value is different from 10 factor. It might why "The Hague" is no specified to be in Netherlands?

Comment: @Larme yes that's correct, the radius doesn't make a difference but it is the keyword. Every time I search with a keyword the compound code is different. If I just get nearby places, compound code is city & country. If I search by keyword, compound code is just city.

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby if you use `keyword`, then your `radius` value is ignored and replaced with `50 000` So if you you don't use `keyword`, but set the radius to `50000`, do you have also only the city?